# What is the easiest / most pythonic way of create a Literal from an enum values?

Tags: python, typechecking

As the question suggests, imagine the following `Enum`:

```py
class Suits(Enum):
    CLUBS = "CLUBS"
    DIAMONDS = "DIAMONDS"
    HEARTS = "HEARTS"
    SPADES = "SPADES"
```

I want to create a `Literal` from the `Enum` values. The only way I managed to do it:

```py
Suit = Literal[Suits.CLUBS, Suits.DIAMONDS, Suits.HEARTS, Suits.SPADES]
```

Which is fine for small enums, but tiring and very error prone for bigger ones.

Hence my question, is there a better way of accomplishing the `Literal` creation?

---

EDIT

As pointed out by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in the comments, we can (should?) use the `Enum` for type checking

Comment: Why do you need the `Literal` in the first place instead of just using `Suits`?

Comment: You are completely right, it was just a question on whether we should use the `Literal` instead of the `Enum`, and, if so, if we could create the type more easily

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `Suits` as a type hint.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most clear and readable way to do it is the following:

```
enum_values_str = [suit.value for suit in Suits]
```

`value` directly gives you the value of an enum and in your case it is a string. Otherwise you could do `str(suit.value)` to convert it to a string.

Comment: Could you expand your answer showing a clear example on how to use `enum_values_str` for type checking?